# Why does Ubuntu (WSL) take 200GB storage space on Windows if I'm using a small fraction of that according to Ubuntu?

Tags: hard-drive, storage

I hope this is the right place to ask, please let me know if it's not and where I should ask this question instead.

[Ubuntu is 214GB acc. to Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSQ4g.png)

According to Windows storage settings, Ubuntu takes 214GB of space, but when I run `df -h`, it says that only 87GB is used.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb        251G   87G  153G  37% /
```

From what I seem to understand by googling, this means that Ubuntu has 153 GB available, but why is the total size 251GB? What does the 251GB mean vs. the 214GB that Windows is reporting. I am trying to free up space, so I was wondering if I could give back some space to Windows?

I hope this made sense, but I may be very confused on what everything is, so some explanation/guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is this a VirtualBox or VMware virtual machine? 

Comment: WSL more likely.

Comment: This is WSL, yep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’ll be because the file system used by Ubuntu (Ext3 or Ext4) isn’t recognised by Windows - so it just sees a partition of a certain size that it can’t use. Ubuntu of course ‘knows’ what is used and what is free within the partition.

So Windows is right in one sense - that amount of space is ‘taken’ by Ubuntu and not available to Windows … but of course Ubuntu knows best - and its version of how much free space is available is indeed correct once you are using Ubuntu.

**EDIT**

sorry, I've read your question a bit more carefully and I've not answered it properly. What I said is true, but it's not really what you're asking - you're (I think) asking why the total amount of space taken by the partition is different between Windows and Ubuntu.

There is a completely different explanation for that: Windows uses powers of 1000 to calculate disk size / useage, df by default displays results using powers of 1024.

From the man page for df, the option `--si` will use powers of 1000 - I think that will then give you the same result as Windows.

The other quirk of df (you haven't asked this but it's interesting) is that your file system will by default reserve 5% of the space for the root user, and as that's neither used nor available to the non-root user, it is not within the available or used space - hence used + free is 5% less than total space.

Apologies for my previously inadequate answer.

Comment: And yes, your question is absolutely fine for this site as it’s about Ubuntu and its use of the partition. Welcome to the site!

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly is that, Ubuntu is given a partition of 251 GB, and that partition cannot be touched by Windows? If so, is there a way to give some of that space back to Windows?

Comment: @piscine - I think your best bet is to post a new question with that specifically. Show full details of your system ... I may have misunderstood but I was assuming it's a dual boot system. Show the details of your OS installations, the disk partitions, and what you're asking and you'll get an answer.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll add a new question, it's not a dual-boot system, the Ubuntu portion is WSL